# How can we Like and comment of a Facebook Post from android application

Tags: android, facebook

How can we Like and comment of a Facebook Post from android application.  Reading this on like Object 
Note: As of Nov 17, 2016 we changed the behavior of publishing likes and only support this action with Page Access Tokens.

I'm not sure how to like a Page Post from android application

Comment: I also need to get facebook that Facebook page post notification counter using graph API

Comment: You can not like posts as a user any more via API.